# Is ui-router compatible with ngRoute?

Tags: angularjs, routes, angular-ui-router

I'd like to use ui-router module in my new application. 
But some third-party dependencies are using ngRoute.

Can I just remove ngRoute and replace it with ui-router module without breaking these third-party dependencies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, If third-party dependency is using ngRoute then you don't have to worry about it. They will manage there dependencies at there own.

But if they have written in there document that we must have to use ngRoute then, you have to use it

Comment: If third-party component uses ngRoute, and I want to use ui-route, should I include both ngRoute.js and ui-route.js script files in my application?

Comment: Nope, include ui-router alone.

If you've third party link, then let me know. I will check and let you know.

Comment: wow, it's great! Thanks!  It's just a general question, so no link for now.